# Change color of selectable UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` with an email address, and I want to set it so that when the user taps on it it will bring up the email controller. So I set the `selectable` and `dataDetectorTypes` attributes, and entered the required email address as the `UITextView`'s text.

This works fine but the issue is that the automatic highlighting of the text in IOS7 is the same shade of blue as the background of my `UIViewController`. So basically the text disappears, and I need to change its color.

Looking around people recommend changing the text, font, and text color only after setting the text view to `selectable`. But it doesn't seem to work. No matter which color I'm trying to set it to, it remains the same shade of blue.

Any idea? This is the code I'm using:

```
UITextView* emailText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 230, 280, 40)];
emailText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
emailText.editable = NO;
emailText.scrollEnabled = NO;
emailText.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
if(IS_OS_7_OR_LATER) {
    emailText.selectable = YES;
}
emailText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSansHebrew-Bold" size:28];
emailText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
emailText.text = @"our email address";
[self.view addSubview:emailText];
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting a `UIView` underneath the `UITextView` (see my question) which makes it straightforward to have any background color I want.

It would have been nicer if I could just choose a color for the `UITextView`'s text, but I guess this is an acceptable workaround.

```
UIView *emailFrameView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 230, 280, 50)];
emailFrameView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
emailFrameView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
[self.view addSubview:emailFrameView];
```